# Updating background Image of JSF component inputText

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I'm trying to update the background image of my text field.

Here's the input text field:

```
<h:inputText label="#{spv.propDef.displayName}" value="#{spv.value}" styleClass="fieldValidation"
disabled="#{spv.disabled}" onkeyup="Validation.checkType(this,  '#{spv.propDef.getDataType().name()}');">
    </h:inputText>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var GAValidation = function(){
'use strict';

var that = {};
var regex = /^(>=( ){0,1}-?\d+|<=( ){0,1}-?\d+|>( ){0,1}-?\d+|<( ){0,1}-?\d+|-?\d+|<>( ){0,1}\d+|<> -?\d+ to -?\d+|-?\d+ to -?\d+)$/;
that.checkType = function(input, type){
     var c = false; 
     if(regex.test(input.value)){
         c=true;
    }
    if(c){
        console.log("Valid");
        $(input).addClass("green");
    }else{
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
};

return that;
}();
```

my css:

```
.green {
background-image: url('#{request.contextPath}/resources/gfx/valid_textfield.png');
```

}

I see the `console.log("Valid");` being executed and the element also has the class added (I checked that by inspecting it) but the image is not being updated. I am able to update the color using `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the background-image url in rendered css (whether the #{request.contextPath} el returns the correct url)